# Laravel response 405 to OPTIONS requests

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, cors

In Laravel We must handle preflight requests by middleware or other ways. In my case, I did many but it never solved!

Here are what I tried,

- **Handle By Middleware**
  In this case, I did create a new middleware and put this code as `handle` method.

`public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'); }`

and I added this to the `$middleware` array in *kernel.php*

- **Using laravel-cors**

I used the *laravel-cors* library to handle cors but not works too

- **Adding cors handle codes in *public/index.php***

I added below codes at top of the *public/index.php* file,

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]) === true) {
    $origin = $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"];
    $allowed_origins = array(
        "https://tapesh.io",
        "http://tapesh.io",
        "http://my.tapesh.io",
        "http://panel.tapesh.io",
    );
    if (in_array($origin, $allowed_origins, true) === true) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Type, Origin');
    }
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "OPTIONS") {
        exit; // OPTIONS request wants only the policy, we can stop here
    }
}
```

- **Apache config**

Also, I checked the apache error logs. the error was something like this,

> [Sat Dec 07 07:35:36.678676 2018] [allowmethods:error] [pid 7902:tid
>   139855840466688] [client 84.417.45.0:4012] AH01623: client method
>   denied by server configuration: 'OPTIONS' to
>   /home/main/domains/example.com/private_html/api

I googled that and find out to handle this with apache I should add `Require all granted` to the Apache 2.4 config file of my domain. I did but not worked!

I must also say, in other projects, I used **laravel-cors** library and it solved mine.

I really confused about!

Comment: That error does indicate that the problem is an apache configuration problem. Go through [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration) *carefully* to be absolutely sure you've covered all possible scenarios. There are links to other mods (like e.g. [mod_allowmethods](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_allowmethods.html)) that may cause this as well if enabled.

Comment: I already did this! I put the solution in the *.htaccess* and the user *httpd.conf* file. but It not worked! Also, I'm not an expert in apache config! @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

try adding the headers in your routes.php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

add more Allow-* headers if you want to. but of course, I suggest you use your code in 'Adding cors handle codes in public/index.php' section of your question in routes.php, because that's a safer bet

Comment: I did before! The problem is about server configuration.